# Non-compete agreement

Tags: hiring-process

I accepted an offer with a company in Ohio and signed a pre-employment non-compete agreement with them.  I am considering now taking another offer and have not started with the initial company.  Is the non-compete agreement enforceable if I have not started employment with the company?

Comment: You should contact a lawyer who specializes in employment law in Ohio

Answer (score 4):

That's a question for a lawyer, not an internet message board.   Laws can vary according to the state.    Chances are the company wouldn't really enforce it, and would let you out of it, as you really have no secrets to share, but that's not something we could really say.